# Why does the doctest fail?

Tags: python, class, doctest

I made a class in Python to perform some basic operations.

```
class perform(object):

    def add(self, first, second):
        """Adds two numbers
        >>>perform().add(1, 2)
        3
        Also adds string
        >>>perform().add('some', 'thing')
        'something'
        """
        return first+second
```

I don't understand why does the doctest failed for the `add` function.

Comment: Doesn't doctest tell you exactly why it fails?

Comment: Note that is covered in the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#how-are-docstring-examples-recognized

Answer (score 2):

You need to add some spaces and a blank line into docstring

```
class perform(object):
    def add(self, first, second):
        """Adds two numbers
        >>> perform().add(1, 2)
        3

        Also adds string
        >>> perform().add('some', 'thing')
        'something'
        """
        return first+second
```

Comment: @HimanshuMishra https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#how-are-docstring-examples-recognized doctest will look for a blank line or a line starting with `>>>` to determine when expected output ends